# Excel Score Calculation

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet with 3 columns that I use to keep track of what someone scores per-question on my exam, for example:

```
WEIGHT GRADE TEST
50     PASS  Do the first thing right
25     PASS  Do the second thing right
25     FAIL  Do the third thing right
```

I want to automatically determine the SCORE by doing the following:

```
SCORE = SCORE + (if B2 == PASS then A2, else 0) + (if B3 == PASS then A3, else 0)
```

So in the case above the student would have gotten a score of 75% (50+25+0). I have many such tests with many students and I just want to paste in the GRADE column and get a final % result in cell C1.

How could I go about writing such a formula in excel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in *C1*

`=SUM(IF(B$2:B$4="PASS",A$2:A$4,0))`

Entered as Array Formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I should look like this in the formula bar: (with curly braces)

[image]

Comment: cell ranges within IF do not seem to work (returns #VALUE!), if I do it for a single row it works fine - so like this: =SUM(IF(B$2="PASS",A$2,0))

Comment: @JSchwartz Did you press CSE combination in the formula bar?